# Customise Create Item & View Item page

Tags: 2013, list, list-item

I'd like to apply heavy customizations to the Create Item & View Item page.

It's an external list pulling data from WCF, and I'm using SP 2013

e.g.

1. Group fields
2. Layout in 2 columns on first half of the page, and 3 columns on the other half
3. Put 2 or more fields on one line, for example: Address has 3 textboxes (City/State/Postcode) in one line

Should I use JSLink or something else?

Could someone please provide some samples..?

Answer (score 0):

To perform the level of customization you are talking about, you can leverage InfoPath or client-side rendering (JS Link).  These two Microsoft references provides a good overview of the InfoPaht approach.  Both are geared toward SharePoint 2010 since prior to SharePoint 2013, this was one of the only ways to do this, but they should work the same for SharePoint 2013.

- [How to: Customize External List Forms Using Microsoft
  InfoPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554886%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Customize a SharePoint list form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-HA101821257.aspx)

Here's a good link on [client-side rendering](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a), but I do not have a SharePoint 2013 environment to play with at the moment.

Comment: Thanks ErinsMatthew, This looks good! I'll give it a try this later this week! thanks again!! :)